# How do I run a Python program over multiple files in a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell

I am trying to run a Python script that takes an image as an input, processes it, and then outputs it as a new file.

If I run this in a Powershell window, it works fine:

```
python neural_style.py -content_image .\images\0.png -style_image .\starry_night.jpg -model_file models\vgg19-d01eb7cb.pth -init image -original_colors 1 -image_size 1280 -save_iter 50 -gpu 0 -backend cudnn
```

What I would like to do is iterate this multiple times for over 1000 images.

I need the -content_image argument, which is currently set to :

> .\images\0.png

to increase by one each time (so for example, after the program finishes with .\images\0.png it moves on to .\images\1.png and so on).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the png files are just sequential numbers, you can loop through a range.

```bsh
0..1000 | Foreach-Object { & python neural_style.py -content_image .\images\$($_).png ... }
```

Comment: This perfect, thank you so much. I have one other question for you, if you don't mind. I would also like to change the name of the output file to correspond to the name of the input file.

At the moment I have this:

`1..1240 | Foreach-Object { & python neural_style.py -style_image .\source.jpg -content_image $($_).png -output_image E:\Pictures\$($_).png }`

However, the output image doesn't seem to be able to use the same variable as is being used by the content image.

Comment: If `-output_image` is the correct parameter and you are not saving to the same path, then that should work. I've not done any python for a long time, so can't remember whether you need to use double slashes for Windows directory names i.e. `-output_image E:\\Pictures\\$($_).png`.

Comment: Ah you were right, sorry I had another mistake in there. Thank you so, so, so much. I really appreciate it and this knowledge is great to have for so many future tasks.

No double slashes needed by the way.